# Change bootstrap webpage font size when

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

How can I allow users to change web page -built with bootstrap- font size when clicking on a button? I would like to change all components font size relatively. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually done with Javascript and cookies. Here's an example using jQuery:

- [Quick and Easy jQuery Font Resizer
  Tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/3956/quick-and-easy-jquery-font-resizer-tutorial)

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap uses global `@baseFontSize` parameter that controls font size of all elements, but changing it would require re-compilation of the css with [less](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: Isn't this possible using jquery?

Comment: You could update font-size property for all elements on the page using jQuery, but there is no bootstrap-specific way to do it.

Comment: At this time, there are some font sizes that are not calculated based upon `baseFontSize`.