# Bootstrap: Tab Font-Size not changing with CSS

Tags: css, tabs, twitter-bootstrap, font-size

I'm trying to change the font-size of the Twitter Bootstrap tabs on a webpage. Seems like a simple thing, but for some reason it is not working.

Everything works in my JSfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ww5Cw/.

However, it is not working properly on the actual webpage: http://chooserealtoday.com/new.html (scroll down a little bit - only tabs on the page).

I've changed the font-size to 22px via Google Chrome Inspector (.nav-tabs li a) and it works, but when I add `.nav-tabs li a {font-size:22px;}` to my `styles.css`, it doesn't seem to work. I've also tried `.nav-tabs > li > a`.

Any thoughts on why this is? Thanks!

Comment: tabs are coming up at 22px for me on your page, is this issue resolved?

Comment: @AndresIlich It is resolved. I just can't accept my own answer yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried a lot of things, even using jQuery to change the font-size, but nothing worked, because as David said, the font is hardcoded into Bootstrap.

I eventually added one line of CSS after `bootstrap-responsive.css` and that got it working.

```
<!-- Le styles -->
<link href="assets/bootstrap2-2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/bootstrap2-2/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
  .nav-tabs li a {font-size:22px;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The font is hardcoded into Bootstrap unfortunately. There are a couple threads that you can take a look at where people have asked similar questions and received some instruction on how to work around.

[navbar color in Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869610/navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap)

[Change bootstrap webpage font size when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659018/change-bootstrap-webpage-font-size-when)

Answer (score 0):

May be your style.css connects before the other and therefore the property is overwritten. Try set the order of connection css files.

Or try to add font-size property to ul or li.

Answer (score 0):

use the directive (!important)
for example:
font-size: smaller !important;